# Cálculo apresentado errado

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float dobro_do_maior(float x, float y)
{
    float dobro;
    if(x > y)
    {
        dobro = x * 2;
    }else{
        dobro = y * 2;
    }
    return dobro;

}

void main()
{
    float a, b, resultado;
    printf("Digite dois numeros: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    resultado = dobro_do_maior(a, b);
    printf("o dobro é %f\n", resultado);

}
```

O problema é que esse algoritmo está apresentado valor zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é que o [padrão de formatação usado no `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) está errado, está usando para entrar com um inteiro e quer um tipo de ponto flutuante que é o `%f`. Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float dobro_do_maior(float x, float y) {
    return x > y ? x * 2 : y * 2;
}

int main() {
    float a, b;
    printf("Digite dois numeros: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("o dobro é %f\n", dobro_do_maior(a, b));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tEuktX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ahjjxnit-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfFormatFloat.c).